# How to get Temp Table Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, templates

I am new to EF. How get data from temp table using Entity Framework?

These are my database tables:

[image: Orignal]

[image: Temp Tabels]

I am not able to get data from the temp table `History.Cites` in my context:

[image: EF main context]

Please help me - thanks.

Comment: is it temp table or different schema based table?

Answer (score 1):

The context you are using does not mapped in `tempdb`.

To get data from the temp table you need:

1. SQL Queries:

`using (var context = new CatalogMainContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Cities.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM #HistoryCities").ToList(); 
}`

2. Load entities from SQL Procedure:

For example, the following code calls the `dbo.GetHistoryCities` procedure in the database:

`using (var context = new CatalogMainContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Cities.SqlQuery("dbo.GetHistoryCities").ToList(); 
}`